# How to escape double slash in Jade?

Tags: pug

I have this in my jade file. But why is it returning error when having two consecutive slashes?

```
p.
    Hayley Kiara #[span http://referral.kiara.com/link.php?member=doe].
```

Thanks for those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

`#[span my text]` is kind of a block expansion which seems in this way to not yet fully supported, there is also no information about it in the official documentation. Usually you can escape strings in jade/pug like as with JavaScript: `\/` or `\"`.

But you can use an escaped string interpolation with a predefined variable or just plain text (by using standard html) to get to your desired result.

Using an unescaped string interpolation:

```
- var url = 'http://referral.kiara.com/link.php?member=doe'
p.
    Hayley Kiara #[span= url].

// OR without a variable:

p.
    Hayley Kiara #[span= 'http://referral.kiara.com/link.php?member=doe'].
```

Using plain text:

```
p.
  Hayley Kiara <span>http://referral.kiara.com/link.php?member=doe</span>.
```